# Assign a regular expression to a php class const

Tags: php, regex, oop

To make my code more readable, and to add more functions where a particular regular expression is needed.

```
/**
 * Regex, Matching when one of the listed exenstion is on a string.
 * @see https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone
 * @link https://regex101.com/r/fK8jQ2/2
 * @var string
 */
CONST PATTERN_PANTONE_EXTENSION = "/((.*)(\s(C|U|M|TC|TP|T|CV|CVC|CVU|CVP|SWOP|SWOP-Euro|DS|S)))$/";
```

The code i'm using:

```
if(preg_match(PATTERN_PANTONE_EXTENSION, $colorCode, $matches)) {
    return $matches[2];
}
```

When i'm using this, the following error will occur.

```
preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Is it possible to store a regular expression inside a constant?

Comment: have you already escaped your regex?

Comment: Try using `~` instead of `/` delimiters. Also, make sure you are actually using *this* pattern.

Comment: Show your complete pattern.

Comment: When you use a class constant inside the class, it must be preceded with `self`: `self::PATTERN_PANTONE_EXTENSION`

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot of searching! :)

Comment: @ThomasCroonen: note that a regex in PHP is only a string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `self::` to access a class const.

so try

```
if(preg_match(self::PATTERN_PANTONE_EXTENSION, $colorCode, $matches)) {
    return $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is truly a class const, then you are not referencing the constant correctly. You need to include the class name and Scope Resolution Operator like so: `Test::PATTERN_PANTONE_EXTENSION`.

I imagine a notice is being thrown about an undefined constant and your error level is not set high enough to show this. After that it tries to use the literal string "PATTERN_PANTONE_EXTENSION" as a regex, with a delimiter of "P", which obviously is not going to work.

Complete example:

```
class Test {
    /**
     * Regex, Matching when one of the listed exenstion is on a string.
     * @see https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone
     * @link https://regex101.com/r/fK8jQ2/2
     * @var string
     */
    const PATTERN_PANTONE_EXTENSION = "/((.*)(\s(C|U|M|TC|TP|T|CV|CVC|CVU|CVP|SWOP|SWOP-Euro|DS|S)))$/";
}

if(preg_match(Test::PATTERN_PANTONE_EXTENSION, $colorCode, $matches)) {
    return $matches[2];
}
```